# Best way to store uploaded files java application

Tags: java, upload

What's the best way to store uploaded files in web java application? I'm currently storing all uploaded files inside project folder. Unfortunately deploying new version of application is a pain in the arse. Do you have any good practice of storing uploaded files?

Comment: store them in a different place then <.<

Comment: Yeah obvious idea is obvious. I'm just asking about good practice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [recommended way to save files uploaded to a Tomcat servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-files-uploaded-to-a-tomcat-servlet)

Comment: By the way, how so "pain in the arse"? You're the one making a major conceptual mistake, not Java/JSF.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload into Database with Blob Type or your can save the file upload into file system but a external folder example c:/Users/youruser/documents/resources to redeploy do not replace.

```
 FileOutputStream fos  = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("home.dir")+"/resources/file.jpg"); //to save into my documents folder
```

with jackrabbit(JCR) the sintaxis is similar to

```
Node.setProperty(java.lang.String name,Binary value)
```

to store content, i think that the JCR is the best Way

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr-api.html

Comment: Don't want to keep so heavy files in database :)

Comment: also you can create system variable in your servlet context example my_resources_path=c:/.... and in your code read the property System.getProperty("my_resources_path")

Comment: you can use jackrabbit(JCR) database