# Write a file to resources folder in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to know, how to write a file to a resources folder in a Spring MVC project. 
I defined the resources path in a `web-dispatcher-servlet.xml` as
`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"  />`

I read examples about how to read a file from a resources folder. But I want to write a file to a resources folder. I tried

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("file/test.xml").getFile());
    if (file.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("File is created!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
    }
```

But I get a
 `Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: The file already exists?

Comment: No, I want create it

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your call to *getResource("file/test.xml")* is likely returning null.

I'm curious, what is the full path to your XML file? For this to work, the *resources* directory needs to be placed in your *webapp* directory. If you are trying to use the standard Java resources structure (src/main/resources) then that Spring MVC mapping will not work.

EDIT: After seeing your answer to @Ascalonian's comment, this will not work since the file doesn't exist. Like I mentioned earlier, *getResource("file/test.xml")* will return null so the following call to *getFile()* will throw the NPE. Maybe you should check if *getResource* returns null and use that as an indication that the file needs to be created.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to create a `test.xml` file in the directory returned by `getResource()`, try this:

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(".").getFile() + "/test.xml");
if (file.createNewFile()) {
    System.out.println("File is created!");
} else {
    System.out.println("File already exists.");
}
```

Calling `getFile()` on a non-existent directory or file will return null, as explained in Reid's answer.

Comment: this fails on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not write to a file in resource folder, as it will get deleted whenever you do a fresh build. Instead store it in some other location and specify the path in a property file.

You can use the following way to create a file :

```
String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File file = new File(StringUtils.join(rootPath, "/any/path/from/your/project/root/directory/" , "test.xml"));
//Below commented line is what you wish to do. But I recommend not to do so.
//File file = new File(StringUtils.join(rootPath, "/out/resources/file/" , "test.xml"));
file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that, the Resources folder can also be included within a build, how do you think tests pass in a deployed environment?

Comment: @Arsalan As per my understanding, resource folder content/files can be included in build at the root path of your jar. But, I guess you can't read or edit it. In a deployed environment, you need to copy that resource content to a location your jar file can access by writing your code and build/deploy script accordingly.