# Unable to Upload file on the tomcat shared server with war file deployment.

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, plesk

Currently in my web application i am storing the image file into the database and retrieving it from the Bolb field using a Servlet. But i want to store it into the disk space. I am having this project deployed on the server as a war file. The problem i am facing is, i am unable to provide the location to which the file is to be uploaded.

The folder structure that i am getting on the Panel is

```
Root directory
.plesk
cgi-bin
error_docs
httpdocs
   img
```

i have tried to provide the path using this method but got **PathNotFound** Exception

```
<context-param>
<description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
<param-name>file-upload</param-name>
<param-value>httpdocs/img/
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

After reading this link  [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application) I have got some idea but still facing the problem because i am not having a dedicated server an i am having no control over the server.

Help me to solve this problem

Comment: Stick it in a DB if you can't control the server?

Comment: @EvanKnowles actually i am getting database space 20% of the total disk space. So if will save all files into the database, i have to pay unnecessary for the disk space.

Comment: Well, you have to put them on disk somewhere. It'll take up disk space if it's in the DB or in a different location somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to start from full path like

```
<param-value>/var/www/vhosts/subscription.name/httpdocs/img/</param-value>
```