# how to replace filepath ,In that filepath delete some path and also replace \ to /

Tags: java

```
fi.write(file);
out.println("filepath"+file.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("above is actual paht and bellow are replace path");
String proPic = file.getAbsolutePath();
HPIUGS.setImageName(proPic);
System.out.println(HPIUGS.getImageName());
out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
out.println(filePath);
```

Output :

```
C:\Users\Peado Inffitech 5\Desktop\eclipse\jsp\UsersPanel\upload\uploadsPenguins.jpg
```

where I change to get output as:

```
/jsp/UsersPanel/upload/uploadsPenguins.jpg
```

Comment: `replace("\\","/")`.

Comment: Why do you want to delete some from file path.

Comment: but sir  remove part of path which is C:\Users\Peado Inffitech 5\Desktop\eclipse\ how can change

Comment: Why do you want only this. explain it clearly.

Comment: ya sir i want just remove this portion from the path that's it

Comment: C:\Users\Peado Inffitech 5\Desktop\eclipse\

Comment: what you are asking is unclear. Is it your current directory?

Comment: ya sir that is current directory but I use  eclipse  that is path of that eclipse where image is upload and above are the code use to insert path of file at that time change in that path.

Comment: Food for thought: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2422468 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/18664579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String gotString  = "C:\\Users\\Peado Inffitech 5\\Desktop\\eclipse\\jsp\\UsersPanel\\upload\\uploadsPenguins.jpg";


String newString = gotString.replace("C:\\Users\\Peado Inffitech 5\\Desktop\\eclipse", "").replace("\\", "/");

System.out.print(newString);
```

This should work for you if I am not missing out your point horribly.

Comment: Very Very Thanks Sir

Comment: Any reason for unaccepting the answer even after accepting?