# servlet: how to save uploaded file

Tags: java, servlets, inputstream, multipartform-data

I am newbie to servlets, I want to save an uploaded image to a dir in the web directory, here is my code:

```
String fileName = p.getSubmittedFileName();
InputStream fileContent = p.getInputStream();
File uploads = new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/uploads"));

File file = File.createTempFile("somefilename-", ".ext", uploads);

try (InputStream input = p.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(input, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

where `p` is `request.getPart()`.

The file is posted correctly, but I can't save it to the dir, why?

Comment: Do you get an error or exception anywhere?

Comment: @MiserableVariable no, there are no exceptions

Comment: use remote debugging or log statements to find out which part of your code is failing

Comment: Do you need to create the `uploads` directory? Try to create a file with static content, e.g. with the line `testing` first.

Comment: @MiserableVariable the uploads dir is already exist in the web content folder.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application) post.

Comment: Again a getRealPath() victim. Never use that method. Period. Any tutorial source which says otherwise must be blacklisted.

Comment: @BalusC the answer given in the question that you provided, didn't solve my problem, could you please give me an example ?!

Comment: Simply don't save in web directory as explained by the answer. There it is not for.