# JSF2 - How to access webapp folder through url on deployed application to tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2, tomcat7, jsf-2.2

I am working on a project in which I have to create a pdf file at run time and save it in webapp directory and than I have to display it in next view (xhtml). So How do I access webapp through url to display the file in next view. I have deployed the application to tomcat7 container.

```
String pdfFilePath = generatePDFFile(path.concat("/1.pdf"));
```

This is the code to display the pdf in `.xhtml` file

```
<embed src="path" width="718" height="700"/>
```

what should be the `path` in both locations to access the file?

Comment: @BalusC I have gone through this link but this is not what I want to do.I want to first save and than I want to display the pdf in browser.

Comment: The link explains how to do that. If you actually want to permanently save PDF, then head to http://stackoverflow.com/q/18664579 (which is also linked in "See also" of the duplicate).