# Where to store uploaded static files with Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat

I store files uploaded by users as follows:

```
 InputStream inputStream = null;
 OutputStream outputStream = null;

 MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();

 String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
 String path ="C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/uploads/images/";

 try {
   inputStream = file.getInputStream();
   File newFile = new File(path +fileName);
   if (!newFile.exists()) {
     System.out.println(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
     newFile.createNewFile();
   }
   outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
   int read = 0;
   byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

   while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
     outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
   }
 } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally {
   outputStream.close();
 }
```

What must be the path where the uploaded files should be saved? I want to store images and display them in JSP pages.

I initially stored the files in the **webapp/images** folder of my Maven project.  But when the app is redeployed the uploaded files are also getting deleted. How can I solve this problem?

When I upload  in **C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/uploads/images/** I can't get images to display in my JSP page. Get error **Not allowed to load local resource**.

Comment: When your JSP gets rendered in the browser, what does the HTML code for images (`<img src="..." />`) look like?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to store Files on the disk is using the Content Repository API for Java (JCR). I suggest Jackrabbit.

Take a look at this answer [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application)

Comment: I looked link 
There is `File uploads = new File("/path/to/uploads");`
But I don't undastand what path I must write ? Is it be not in my webapp?