# mix binary and character data

Tags: java, servlets

I have an image stored as a byte array and a caption as string under a pojo I call media. How do I return both the byte array and the string to the browser since I can't call both `getoutputstream()` and `getwriter()`? Thanks.

Comment: You don't at all need the `byte[]` during generating HTML output. Just some identifier to use in `<img src>` is sufficient.

Comment: The image is stored as a byte[] in the database. Can you please show me a snippet as what you are explaining. The image is a variable in a pojo class that has other variables too like the caption.

Comment: Just follow the duplicate link. This has already been answered years ago.

Comment: I saw your comment on a similar question that advised that the uploaded file should be stored in a directory and the path to the directory stored on database, please show me how that can be done?

Comment: That's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18664579 If you want more answers to Servlet development related questions, continue here: https://servlets.zeef.com