# Servlet 3.0 throwing excepting when testing File Upload

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm giving a try to the Servlet 3.0 fileupload feature, with the code parsed from here: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-file-upload-example-with-servlet-30-api

Well, I try to upload some file, and I always get the same exceptions:

**Web error:**

> type Exception report
>
> message Internal Server Error
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\usuario1.s00win81\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\UploadingFiles\C:\Users\usuario1.s00win81\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UploadingFiles\build\web\uploadFiles\Soluciones
>   evaluación.txt (El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la
>   sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

**Glassfish server:**

> Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[Servlets.UploadServlet]:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet Servlets.UploadServlet threw exception
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\usuario1.s00win81\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\UploadingFiles\C:\Users\usuario1.s00win81\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UploadingFiles\build\web\uploadFiles\filetest.txt (El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la
>   sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:162)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem.write(PartItem.java:450)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem.write(PartItem.java:505)  at
>   Servlets.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:49)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Am I doing something wrong?

More info:

- JDK 8
- Netbeans 8.1
- Glassfish 4.1
- I tried to upload several files, all of them tiny (just a few KBs).

edit: FIXED

The path was wrong. Actually, I guess that the code I copied wasn't good. I created manually the folder where the uploaded file will go, and just used a relative path instead of an absolute one, and it began to work. Gotta add later a better answer with what I changed!

Comment: Particularly check the "Saving uploaded file" section of the abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: @BalusC This is a different problem... the uploading logic is all here, nothing's missing. This question is to assess the exception I'm having (which I don't find a solution for).

Comment: Ok, I found out what was happening! Gotta edit in a moment

Comment: All due respect, it's not a different problem, Zerok. The duplicate explains that many online sources are doing a terrible bad job in this, and shows the correct way and links to a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579. The code snippet you found is in one word terrible. It's clearly written by an amateur with lack of fundamental understanding. Never ever trust so-called "online tutorial" sites founded somewhere in south east Asia when they are full of copypasted code and advertisement banners. With no exception they are all terrible.