# Generate PDF file into a remot JBoss server

Tags: java, pdf, jboss, remote-server

My application generate PDF and save it in the WAR file. Everything works fine in the localhost but after deploying the WAR under the remote Wildfly server the app can't access the WAR file.

```java
ut.setDestinationFileName( "../../wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/MyApp.war/Rapport/SampleResult.pdf");
```

Comment: It could be permissions issues on your remote server Is this the line that the error is showing? can you add a little more context to this code?

Comment: I suggest the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18664715/1885672 and change your code if you are using absolute path.

Comment: You can use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/...")` or such, but consider whether you cannot stream it out immediately to a `response.getOutputStream()` (maybe in two steps: returning the new page with PDF generating URL). `../../` and such is horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for answering, i found a solution, i don't know if it's the best one but it work:
 MyApp.war is a compressed file and ut.setDestinationFileName() can't access to a compressed file so i create a new folder under                            "wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments" and i name it MyApp.war and there i decompress the real war file and finally i restart the server.