# Path to tomcat folder from html and jsp

Tags: html, spring, maven, tomcat, path

I have spring webapp in maven and users can upload files which are being saved in the tomcat folder, since I use tomcat as the webserver. I have some jsp and html pages, so what is the path to those files uploaded on tomcat server? I guess I don't want to use absolute path on my computer to tomcat folder. And would something change regarding paths, if the app is published on internet on actual server?

Comment: you dont want to use absolute paths. if user deploys your app on another url with another name, your path will change. instead use relative paths within your project.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu Thanks for the answer. So how would I specify path from my controller in src/main/java/controller to webapp folder?

Comment: Read Xavier Bouclet's answer, especially the linked best practices. And *do not* save uploaded files in the `webapps` folder (reasons given in the linked answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's where you want to save it.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application) to find more information about the best practices