# upload images from local window to remote location folder in java

Tags: java, jsp

I am able to upload image locally but not able to upload remotely(i.e another machine).Here is the code..

@WebServlet("/UploadServ")

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final String UPLOAD_DIR1 = "\\\\ip-address\\C$\\upload\\";
public UploadServlet() {
    super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if (!isMultipart) {
    } else {
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory())
                    .parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));

            for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIR1 + name));
                }
            }
            // File uploaded successfully
            System.out.println("File uploaded successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("File uploaded failed..");
        }
    }}
    request.getRequestDispatcher("response.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what problems you are having.

Comment: how i can upload/save image from one machine to other machine?If i write UPLOAD_DIR1 = "C:\\upload\\" then its work fine. but i just want to upload the images in another machine not in same machine.

Comment: The code that you have posted is server side code.  If you want one server to transfer to another server then consider using ftp

Comment: Thanks  Scary Wombat . Can you give me a sample of code so that i can understand.

Comment: why, is your browser broken? Can you not search for code yourself?

Comment: The problem is in your UPLOAD_DIR1 syntax. I will post the correct syntax for the URL when I get home (because I can't remember the exact syntax right now)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the correct folder URL relative to the web content root ("/"), I used the following code

```
final String uploadDir =  request.getRealPath("/ip-address/C$/upload");
```

Then just create a new File object

```
File file = new File( uploadDir, fileName);
```

Note that `getRealPath()` is now deprecated but should still work. According to this answer here ( [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application) ) there are better ways to specify an upload folder but I haven't tried any of these methods.