# Can't get ResourceAsStream from path using ServletContext

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception, inputstream, servletcontextlistener

I have a Servlet that handles the download of an attached File. I get the attached file's path from the request and try to get the resource as stream from it using the ServletContext, but I always get the InputStream as null, the following is my doGet method:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = request.getParameter("path");

    // Fetch File name from path and Then depending on the File extension choose
    // which ContentType using Switch structure
    Path p = Paths.get(path);
    String fileName = p.getFileName().toString();
    Optional<String> fileExtension = Optional.ofNullable(fileName).filter(f -> f.contains("."))
            .map(f -> f.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
    System.out.println("This is File Name: " + fileName);
    System.out.println("This is File Extension: " + fileExtension.orElseGet(null));

    /// Set ContentType of the HTTP header depending on the File
    /// Extensions
    switch (fileExtension.orElseGet(null).toLowerCase()) {
        case "txt":
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            break;
        case "pdf":
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            break;
        case "doc":
            response.setContentType("application/msword");
            break;
        case "docx":
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            break;
        case "xlsx":
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            break;
        case "zip":
            response.setContentType("application/zip");
            break;
        case "jpeg":
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            break;
        case "jpg":
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            break;
        case "png":
            response.setContentType("image/png");
            break;
        case "rar":
            response.setContentType("application/x-rar-compressed");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    //URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
    //InputStream strm=url.openStream();

     try(InputStream in = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(path);
              OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[ARBITARY_SIZE];

        int numBytesRead;
        while ((numBytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

below is the Attachments Folder path:

[image]

Comment: This code makes no sense. The whole servlet is unnecessary. Just link to the URL `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/Attachments/new1.txt` directly instead to the URL of the servlet. Unless this represents an uploaded file .. Then you need to take a step back because saving uploaded files into deploy folder isn't ever going to work reasonably in a production environment.

Comment: Well, I have used that approach using:                                                                      `<a id="attachment-${ticket[0]}" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/Attachments/new1.txt" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Télécharger Attachement" hidden download><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>`

Comment: @ BalusC, What do you suggest as a better approach for the production environment, and if any available resources thanks to provide with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18664579

Comment: @ BalusC,Really appreciate your Help, but still have an issue when I use: File fileSaveDir = new File(getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload")); I get NullPointerException, even though I added <context-param> in web.xml, it works fine when I put the path hardcoded like this: File fileSaveDir = new File("c:/Attachments");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src/main/webapp` is the Servlet root folder, i.e. files and folders in the `webapp` folder are copied into the `.war` file at the root.

The `path` parameter to [`servletContext.getResourceAsStream(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) must be relative to that, and must start with `/`.

So to read that file, you need `path = "/resources/Attachments/new 1.txt"`